# Meaning of the phrase "spurn a chance"

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

The word "spurn" usually means to refuse to accept someone or something. In this context, what does it actually mean?

City **spurn** a strong **chance** to equalise as Silva cuts back inside rather than shooting with his left foot. Soon after Tevez picks up the ball inside the penalty area and uses close control to create space, firing over with a snapshot from 12 yards.

Answer (score 1):

In "normal" English, if you [***spurn***](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/spurn) some opportunity, that means you *reject it with **disdain** or **contempt***.

But in the bizarre world of sports commentary, one might almost say the alluded-to "contempt" actually transfers from the ***player[s]*** who ***failed to score*** ("spurning" the chance to equalise) to the ***commentator***.

That's to say, the commentator is somewhat contemptuously referring to City's failure to score an equalising goal (when they *should* have). That same sense of "unwillingly" or at least, "not deliberately" failing is also commonly used by commentators when they say a team ***threw away*** their chances of victory (by playing badly, but obviously not as a deliberate act, as would *normally* be implied by throwing something away).

---

Sports commentators like saying things like *[the losers]* [***snatched defeat from the jaws of victory***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22snatched%20defeat%20from%20the%20jaws%20of%20victory%22) to express their contempt for a team who *should* have won, but for some reason failed to perform to expectations. That's a similar "semantic reversal device" to ***spurning** a chance to win*.